# How can I save my cardView click event state to save its colour in spite of using shared preferences

Tags: java, android

I was implementing Shared Preferences on my android app where i want to save the click on listener event that the cardView colour is changed and stays that way even if the app is killed or restated but unfortunately i seem not to get it here the code runs perfectly smooth but the cardview state is not saved thanks guys,

**Here is my Fragment with the cardView that i impelemented**

````
```//saving button state after one click of the student
        SharedPreferences preferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("save", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        cardView.setEnabled (preferences.getBoolean ("value",true));




       //setting the click listener to send the request to specific section api anf return response

       cardView.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener () {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               if(cardView.getCardBackgroundColor ().getDefaultColor () ==-1 || textView.getTextColors ().getDefaultColor () ==-1 || cardView.isEnabled ())
               {
                   //change background color
                   cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));
                   textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
                   Toast.makeText (getActivity (),"Request Sent to SNAL",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show ();
                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences ("save",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit ();
                   editor.putBoolean ("value",true);
                   editor.apply ();
                   //disabling the button after one click
                   cardView.setEnabled (true);



               }
               else {

                   cardView.setCardBackgroundColor (Color.parseColor ("#ffffff"));
                   textView.setTextColor (Color.parseColor ("#2b434f"));



                   SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences ("save",Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit ();
                   editor.putBoolean ("value",false);
                   editor.apply ();
                   cardView.setEnabled (true);



               }

           }
       });```
````

Comment: Store your desired color for `CardView` inside `SharedPreference` like you did for `value`

Comment: could you show me how brother

Answer (score 0):

Even if you save the state, you need to add a functionality in your onCreate/onStart/onResume (or whenever before the click) that if the value is true to change the colour to your desired one

Comment: whats that brother

Comment: Those are the first methods that activities executes when the activity is created, you can read about it [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle) in the google docs.

Answer (score 0):

I've looking my own snippets, and the only difference in my code with yours is the "Context.MODE_PRIVATE" if this was my code all those lines were:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getActivity ().getSharedPreferences ("save",MODE_PRIVATE).edit ();
```

So basicly this is not a big deal, but you can try it anyway, it may work, replace

> "Context.MODE_PRIVATE"

with

> "MODE_PRIVATE"

Of course you will also need a method that retrieves those values when the view is being created.